# Android audio streaming over RTP

Tags: android, audio-streaming, vlc, rtp

I have app, that can stream recorded audio to VLC player on my PC.

```
try {

        audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
        audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioStream = new AudioStream(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.218"));
        AudioCodec[] ac = AudioCodec.getCodecs();
        audioStream.setCodec(ac[3]); // ac[3] = AudioCodec.PCMU
        audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_NORMAL);
    }
```

But output audio have only 8000 sample rate.
 How I can change it to 44.1k?

Other codecs than `AudioCodec.PCMU` don't work. No idea why...